# mail arrive without the file php

Tags: php, forms, file, attachment

Next page works, but I do not get the file with the mail when submit.

The mail that arrives:

MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed;
 boundary="==Multipart_Boundary_xa18882382b8d92109533240902ace32ex"

--==Multipart_Boundary_xa18882382b8d92109533240902ace32ex
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="iso-8859-1"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

...and after thet ther is the valius from the inputs ( $msg)

... then

--==Multipart_Boundary_xa18882382b8d92109533240902ace32ex

**without the file

```
<?php 

    if(isset($_FILES) && (bool) $_FILES) {

        $allowedExtensions = array("pdf","doc","docx","gif","jpeg","jpg","png","rtf","txt");
        $files = array();

        foreach($_FILES as $name=>$file) {
            $file_name = $file['name']; 
            $temp_name = $file['tmp_name'];

            $path_parts = pathinfo($file_name);
            $ext = $path_parts['extension'];
            if(!in_array($ext,$allowedExtensions)) {
                die("File extensions not allowed");
            }

            $server_file = "/tmp/$path_parts[basename]";
            move_uploaded_file($temp_name,$server_file);

            array_push($files,$server_file);
        }

    $mail_to = 'dorozenman@gmail.com'; // specify your email here

    // Assigning data from the $_POST array to variables
    $name = $_POST['sender_name'];
    $suname = $_POST['sender_suname'];
    $Bday = $_POST['sender_Bday'];
    $nowWork = $_POST['sender_work'];
    $phone = $_POST['sender_phone'];
    $mail_from = $_POST['sender_email'];
    $free = $_POST['sender_way'];

    // Construct email headers
    $headers = 'From: ' . $mail_from . "\r\n";

    // Construct email subject
    $subject = 'בקשה לרעיון עבודה' . $name;

    // Construct email body
    $msg = 'name: ' . $name . "\r\n";
    $msg .= 'suname: ' . $suname . "\r\n";
    $msg .= 'Bday: ' . $Bday . "\r\n";
    $msg .= 'nowWork: ' . $nowWork . "\r\n";
    $msg .= 'phone: ' . $phone . "\r\n";
    $msg .= 'mail_from: ' . $mail_from . "\r\n";
    $msg .= 'free: ' . $free;

    $semi_rand = md5(time()); 
    $mime_boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$semi_rand}x"; 

    $headers .= "\nMIME-Version: 1.0\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\n";
    $headers .= " boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\""; 

    $message ="\n\n--{$mime_boundary}\n";
    $message .="Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n";
    $message .="Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n" . $msg . "\n\n";
    $message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n";

    foreach($files as $file) {
        $aFile = fopen($file,"rb");
        $data = fread($aFile,filesize($file));
        fclose($aFile);
        $data = chunk_split(base64_encode($data));
        $massage .= "Content-Type: {\"application/octet-stream\"};\n";
        $massage .= " name=\"$file\"\n";
        $massage .= "Content-Disposition: attachment;\n";
        $massage .= " filename=\"$file\"\n";
        $massage .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" . $data . "\n\n";
        $massage .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n";
    }

    $mail_sent = mail($mail_to, $subject, $message, $headers);

        if ($mail_sent){ ?>
            <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
            alert('yay');

            </script>
            <?php } else { ?>
            <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">  
            alert('nay');

        </script>
        <?php     
        }

   }    
?>
```

What's wrong? Why I'm not getting the file if I do not get any php warning from the page?

Comment: Simple: don't build your own mime emails. ALl of that mime-generating code could be reduced to a **SINGLE** line of PHPMailer or Swiftmailer calls.

Answer (score 1):

You are typecasting your $_FILES (array) to be a bool, in your if statement. You should write is_array($_FILES) instead of (bool) $_FILES, then you should get your file.

Comment: i put the:  if(is_array($_FILES) )...    instad of  if(isset($_FILES) && (bool) $_FILES)  still the same result